# Adding a header and footer in a SharePoint Online word document

Tags: sharepoint-online

We want to add a header and footer to multiple SharePoint Online documents.
Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a content type from site settings and upload the Word document with header and footer to it. Then add the content type to the document library.

To programmatically add headers and footers to documents, take a reference to this article: [Programmatically add headers and footers to documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-headers-and-footers-to-documents?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#programmatically-add-headers-and-footers-to-documents).